# Make \section behave like \part for the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, parts

I want to make my table of contents as if I'm using `\parts` and `\sections` throughout my document, as in the following picture: [image: ToC that I like.]

It's neat and easy to read. However I don't like the way it looks throughout my document; it makes it look rather messy and space consuming as in the following picture: [image: Document I do not like.].

I prefer using `\section` and `\subsection` throughout my document, in my opinion it looks much nicer, as in this picture: [image: Document that I like.]

But this makes the table of contents look cluttered and difficult to read, like this: [image: ToC I do not like.]

How do I make my table of contents behave as if I have used `\part` and `\section` throughout my document, whilst having used only `\section` and `\subsection`, respectively, throughout?

That is, how can I make my ToC behave as in the first picture, and make my document look like the 3rd picture?

Comment: can you add a MWE please ? what class are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make my table of contents behave as if I have used \part and \section throughout my document, whilst having used only \section and \subsection, respectively, throughout?

To do *exactly* that,
you can trick the table of contents into thinking that your section is a part, and your subsection is a section, by putting this into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@subsection\l@section
\let\l@section\l@part
\makeatother
```

Which results in this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\let\l@subsection\l@section
\let\l@section\l@part
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{Looks like part}
  \lipsum[1]
  \subsection{Looks like section}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The output (mind that I might not have the same formatting options or document class as you do):

[image: Output of TeX code above]

**Edit:** Messed up the order. Fixed now!

Comment: Thanks, this had the intended effect. I forgot to add the document class I'm using, which is amsart.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.